# What's the relationship between the numerators and denominators of convergents of a continued fraction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, self-learning, continued-fractions

I'm working on a question from a past exam paper,

> Let $C_n=\frac{p_q}{q_n}$ be the convergents of a finite continued fraction. State the $p$-$q$ relation and prove it.

I don't yet have access to course notes. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents) gives a way to calculate $p_{n+1}$ from $p_n$ and $q_{n+1}$ from $q_n$, but I don't see any mention of a $p$-$q$ relation. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1493941/596895) states that each pair $p_n,q_n$ is coprime and gives the relation $p_nq_{n+1}-q_np_{n+1}=\pm1$. But the $p_q$ notation in the numerator of the exam question suggests that $p$ can be actually expressed in terms of $q$. Can it?

Comment: The $p_q$ is probably a typo

Comment: @Peter I did wonder about that. Bit awkward during an exam. Do you suppose $p_nq_{n+1}-q_np_{n+1}=\pm1$ is "the $p$-$q$ relation"?

Comment: Hard to say , but this would make sense and can actually be proven using the recurrence relations for $p$ and $q$ and induction.